# How to initialize a tuple with a given class having no copy constructor

Tags: c++, tuples, tuple-packing

I have a requirement where tuple needs to be initialized as follows. How do I create a tuple containing class A's object?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

class A{
  int a;

public:
  A(const A&)=delete;
  A(int a): a(a){}
};

std::tuple<A>& createTuple(A &&a){
  return std::make_tuple<A>(std::forward<A>(a));
}
int main(){
  std::cout << std::get<0>(createTuple(std::forward<A>(A(1))));
}
```

I can't modify the class A in any manner.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do, and what are your _actual_ constraints? I mean, we can probably deduce/guess it from your code in this case, but you should use _words_ to explain it so that this question is searchable and re-usable and clear.

Comment: `std::forward` doesn't work the way you think it works. In your case you don't need `std::forward` anywhere.

Comment: also in `createTuple` you are trying to return an lvalue reference to a temporary object. I

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
std::tuple<A> t(1);
```

`A`'s move constructor isn't implicitly declared since you `delete`d the copy constructor (which should take an `A const&` btw), so the form you're trying to use wouldn't be valid outside of `tuple` anyway:

```
A a = A(1); // error
```

If you need a move constructor, you'll need to explicitly write one:

```
A(A&& rhs) = default;
```

at which point this would work:

```
std::tuple<A> t(A(1));
```

Note that the `forward` is redundant since `A(1)` is already an rvalue.

---

> I can't modify the class `A` in any manner.

Given that, you cannot make a `std::tuple<A>`. The member `int` is private, so you can't access it to use the `int` constructor like I initially proposed. There is no move constructor, so you can't use that one either. Those were your two options - neither of which are apparently viable.

Moreover, you cannot even make a `std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<A>>` since again `A` is noncopyable and you have no way to get at the `int` member.

Game over, man. Game over.

Comment: Thanks, two things I can't modify the Class A and can't create a tuple object like std::tuple<A> t(1);, as the object of a is being passed from another function. I am updating the question please check it out.

Comment: @AAA Those are your two options. I see no question update.